# How to center an element in a div, while keeping it on the same horizontal level as another element?

Tags: html, css

Having trouble getting my image to center, while remaining on the same horizontal level as my icon.

**HTML**

```
<div class="smalltop w3-top">
  <span class="w3-opennav w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()"><i id="menui" class="material-icons w3-xxlarge">menu</i></span>
  <a href="#"><img id="smalllogo" src="img/navlogo-invert.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#smalllogo {
  max-height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#menui {
  left: 0;
}

.smalltop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzLbruhx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add relative positioning to the container and absolute positioning to the icon

```
#menui {
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
}
.smalltop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pzLbruhx/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just give property `float:left` to `#menui`, and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`display:table\table-row\table-cell`**](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero) and [**`vertical-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) on icon

```
#smalllogo {
  max-height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.w3-opennav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.smalltop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table-row;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/xqzks64t/1/)